# How to save an array to a Realm Object

Tags: arrays, json, swift, realm

I am new to using Realm. Is there an easy way to save an array to a realm object? I am receiving my data from a JSON REST call:

```
class SomeClass: RLMObject {

    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var array: NSArray


    func checkForUpdates() {
        // Download JSON data here... The results have an array inside of them.

        SomeClass.createOrUpdateInDefaultRealmWithObject(SomeNSDictionary)         


    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String! {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to save the array in the JSON results in Realm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Realm has a special `RLMArray` type, which allows storing a collection of `RLMObject`'s tied to a parent `RLMObject`. For example, say you had the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "aliases": [
    {"alias": "John"},
    {"alias": "JD"}
  ]
}
```

You could model this with the following classes:

```
class Alias: RLMObject {
  dynamic var alias = ""
}

class Person: RLMObject {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var aliases = RLMArray(objectClassName: "Alias")
}
```

So you could simply create a `Person` object with the following API call:

```
Person.createInRealm(realm, withObject: jsonObject)
```

You can learn more about how `RLMArray`s work from Realm's reference documentation: http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.80.0/api/Classes/RLMArray.html

Comment: Do you mind showing the code using Objective-C? I am facing this problem too.

Comment: Do I have to define "Alias" jsut to store an array of IDs for example?