# Realm 0.102.0 save RLMArray

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've already read alike answers (eg. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135188/how-to-save-an-array-to-a-realm-object)) but it did not work for me.

I have:

```
import Realm
import RealmSwift

class Ticket: Object {

    dynamic var ticketDetails = RLMArray(objectClassName: TicketDetail.className())

}

class TicketDetail: Object {
}
```

When I create a new ticket, app crash at this line:

```
// Helper for getting the list object for a property
internal func listForProperty(prop: RLMProperty) -> RLMListBase {
    return object_getIvar(self, prop.swiftIvar) as! RLMListBase
}
```

with:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

On console I print "prop":

```
po prop
ticketDetails {
    type = array;
    objectClassName = TicketDetail;
    linkOriginPropertyName = (null);
    indexed = NO;
    isPrimary = NO;
    optional = NO;
}
```

If I print "self":

```
Ticket {
   ticketDetails = RLMArray <0x7fee6c1d7880> (
    [0] TicketDetail {
    }
   );     
}
```

So what? I can't figure out why crash! Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing types from the Realm Swift API (`Object`) and Realm Objective-C API (`RLMArray`) in a way that's not supported. If you stick to using only one API you'll have better luck. For instance, with Realm Swift you would write your model as:

```
import RealmSwift

class Ticket: Object {
    let ticketDetails = List<TicketDetail>()
}

class TicketDetail: Object {
}
```

Comment: I know and I always try with your method, but with this signature I have a compile error "Property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in Objective-c". I need to declare property dynamic in order to be persisted, isn't it?

Comment: +1 for this answer. You should use All Swift or All ObjC classes from Realm. I prefer to use Swift classes with Swift project.

Comment: @LucaDavanzo you can only declare `dynamic` for ObjectiveC type, `List` is a pure Swift object, there is no need to use `dynamic` modifier. It will get persisted by Realm just fine.

Comment: Let me try and I'll give you feedback!